# What are the most important rugby union club leagues?

Tags: rugby-union

What are the most important rugby union club leagues in the world? By "most important" I mean the leagues where the players are professional and where the teams are able to win international cups and/or tournaments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given the relatively limited geographical distribution of rugby union, it's not entirely surprising that the top leagues are in the top Test playing nations:

- [Super Rugby](http://www.superxv.com/) in Australia, New Zealand and South Africa; in 2016, expanded to include Argentina and Japan.
- [Top 14](http://www.lnr.fr/rugby-top-14) in France.
- [Premiership Rugby](http://www.premiershiprugby.com/home.php) in England.
- [Pro14](https://www.pro14rugby.org/home.php) in Ireland, Italy, Scotland, and Wales; in 2017, expanded to include two South African clubs removed from Super Rugby.

Other than those leagues, the other major club competition is the [European Rugby Champions Cup](http://www.epcrugby.com/home.php), which matches the top teams from England, France, Ireland, Italy, Scotland and Wales (the Six Nations countries) from the previous year.